# Post-Login Connection Error creating OpenShift application in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, openshift, jboss-tools

I have been following the directions for using Eclipse to create a PHP Openshift application found at https://blog.openshift.com/deploy-php-to-the-cloud-with-eclipse-openshift-and-pdt/ and I have installed the jBoss plugin and the sign-on appears to work, but I get a "Problem Occurred" alert with the error message

'Loading Data...' has encountered a problem. Could not load applications.

The "details" of the message are "Could not load applications, Unknow request parameter type integer"

After this error message I'm unable to select an existing application, or specify a Type for a new project, so I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an outdated version of the OpenShift tools for Eclipse. See here: https://forums.openshift.com/create-project-in-the-eclipse-error-unknow-request-parameter-type-integer
The solution is very simple: install and use the latest JBoss Developer Studio (8.0.2) or Eclipse (Luna) and JBoss Tools (4.2.2.Final): http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/

Cheers
André